# phpmyadmin returns too wrong database after timeout

Tags: phpmyadmin, lamp

How to let *phpmyadmin* return to the correct database after the session timeout?

I'm using *phpmyadmin* to manage my databases, I have multiple databases with similar structures.

When I'm working in one of them, and the session timeouts I need to re-login. But after login I'm in another database. Everything else is similar: I'm in the same table, if I submitted something before the timeout I went to the correct page.

Is this related to the login name/rights or is this a configuration setting?

Comment: This same thing happens to me - except it tries to bring up the table I had open on another database, which doesn't exist on the database it's trying to access after timeout.  Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

This works okay for me with version 4; perhaps try upgrading your phpMyAdmin and try again.

There is no configuration for it nor is it related to login rights.

Comment: Did you had this same problem with previous versions?
i'm kind of depended on the ubuntu release, i'm not keen on buggy pre-release versions.

Comment: Well first of all, version 4 is fully released and stable, it's not buggy or a pre-release. Secondly, Ubuntu Saucy does package 4.0.5, so even staying on Ubuntu there are different phpMyAdmin versions available, which depends on what Ubuntu version you're tied to. With which phpMyAdmin version do you have this problem?

Comment: okey correction you're right.
the problem i'm having is Directadmin.
when upgrading from directadmin custombuild it says  
installed version of phpmyadmin: 3.5.8.2
latest version of phpmyadmin: 3.5.8.2
i'll look into directadmin why it isn't upgrading!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Directadmin, perhaps someone else will have some thoughts.

Comment: Solved the upgrade, now running 4.0.5   
have to see and wait if the error comes back.